# Beautiful soup finding the first sibling of a known object with a known attribute

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, siblings

I have the following code to select a certain cell in a table element:

`tag = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'I'})`

as shown in the attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmjBe.png), I would like to somehow be able to find its first sibling within the same class "even_row". Ideally, the selection would output only the contents of data-seconds, in this case "58". Not every "even_row" class has a  element with class I, and some have more than one, so I need to get the value data-seconds only for the "even_row" classes that have the  element with class "I"

Any help would be appreciated as I've been banging my head on the wall looking through documentation to no avail.

html look like :

```
<tr class='even_row'>
<td class='row_labels' data-seconds="58">
    <div class='celldiv slots1'></div>
</td>
<td class='new'>...</td>
<td class='I'>...</td>
<td class='new'>...</td>
<td class='new'>...</td>
```

Comment: post the `html` source as code here. do not post it as image to make it easier for us.

Comment: Something like this is easier to do with xpath, which is supported by lxml, but not beautifulsoup.

Comment: please use snippet tool via [edit] to add the html to the question so we can copy it for testing. Also, can you share the url if it is public?  Make sure sample html is representative to the scenario you describe with its various cases to cater for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around that issue is to pass True

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<tr class='even_row'>
    <td class='row_labels' data-seconds="58">
        <div class='celldiv slots1'></div>
    </td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
    <td class='I'>...</td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='even_row'>
    <td class='row_labels' >
        <div class='celldiv slots1'></div>
    </td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
    <td class='I'>...</td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
    <td class='new'>...</td>
</tr>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
even_rows = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class': 'even_row'})
for row in even_rows:
    tag = row.find("td", {"data-seconds" : True})
    if tag is  not None:
        print(tag.get('data-seconds'))
```

Output :

```
58
```

another way to do it is using regular expressions

```
import re
tds = [tag.get('data-seconds') for tag in soup.findAll("td", {"data-seconds" : re.compile(r".*")})]
print(tds)
```

Output :

```
['58']
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot test properly without the html but sounds like with bs4 4.7.1+ you can use `:has` to satisfy your requirements for `.even_row:has(.I)` i.e. parent with class `even_row`, having child with class `I`, and then add in  `[data-seconds]` to cater for all child  `data-seconds` attribute values

```
print([i['data-seconds'] for i in soup.select('.even_row:has(.I) [data-seconds]')])
```